# Why is my cURL POST data not populating fields?

Tags: php, post, curl

I have searched through previous posts, but cannot find an example of the same issue using a similar code approach.

I am submitting data via cURL to a remote URL, before sending the user to a 'thanks' confirmation page.

When I submit the form (full code below), the remote URL fields are not populated and every form field remains empty:

```
<?php
// Setup empty fields
$SubmitForm_first_name = $SubmitForm_last_name = $SubmitForm_job_title = "";
$SubmitForm_first_nameError = $SubmitForm_last_nameError = $SubmitForm_job_titleError = "";

// Validate Field Entry
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $valid = true; // Redirect if valid

    if (empty($_POST["SubmitForm_first_name"]))
    {$valid = false; $SubmitForm_first_nameError = "First name required";}
        else
        {$SubmitForm_first_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["SubmitForm_first_name"]);}

    if (empty($_POST["SubmitForm_last_name"]))
    {$valid = false; $SubmitForm_last_nameError = "Surname required";}
        else
        {$SubmitForm_last_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["SubmitForm_last_name"]);}

    if (empty($_POST["SubmitForm_job_title"]))
    {$valid = false; $SubmitForm_job_titleError = "Job title required";}
        else
        {$SubmitForm_job_title = htmlspecialchars($_POST["SubmitForm_job_title"]);}

// Start session
session_start();

// Register
session_register('SubmitForm_first_name');
session_register('SubmitForm_last_name');
session_register('SubmitForm_job_title');

// Populate
$_SESSION['SubmitForm_first_name'] = $SubmitForm_first_name;
$_SESSION['SubmitForm_last_name'] = $SubmitForm_last_name;
$_SESSION['SubmitForm_job_title'] = $SubmitForm_job_title; 

// Redirect valid form to process
if($valid)
    //set POST variables
    { $url = 'http://www.example.com/submit.php';
    $fields = array(
                        'SubmitForm[first_name]' => urlencode($SubmitForm_first_name),
                        'SubmitForm[last_name]' => urlencode($SubmitForm_last_name),
                        'SubmitForm[job_title]' => urlencode($SubmitForm_job_title)
                    );

    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    // redirect to thank you page
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/thanks.php');
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="submit_data" method="POST" id="submit_data">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Your Details</legend>
                    <p><label for="SubmitForm_first_name">First Name</label><input type="text" id="SubmitForm_first_name" size="20" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $SubmitForm_first_name;?>" name="SubmitForm_first_name" /><br /><span class="error"> <?php echo $SubmitForm_first_nameError;?></span></p>
                    <p><label for="SubmitForm_last_name">Surname</label><input type="text" id="SubmitForm_last_name" size="20" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $SubmitForm_last_name;?>" name="SubmitForm_last_name" /><br /><span class="error"> <?php echo $SubmitForm_last_nameError;?></span></p>
                    <p><label for="SubmitForm_job_title">Job Title</label><input type="text" id="SubmitForm_job_title" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $SubmitForm_job_title;?>" name="SubmitForm_job_title" /><br /><span class="error"> <?php echo $SubmitForm_job_titleError;?></span></p>
            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, if I do a direct HTTP post (code example below), every field populates correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>

    <form action="http://www.example.com/submit.php" name="inputData" method="POST" id="inputData">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Your Details</legend>
                    <p><label for="SubmitForm_first_name">First Name</label><input type="text" id="SubmitForm[first_name]" size="20" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $SubmitForm_first_name;?>" name="SubmitForm[first_name]" /><br /><span class="error"> <?php echo $SubmitForm_first_nameError;?></span></p>
                    <p><label for="SubmitForm_last_name">Surname</label><input type="text" id="SubmitForm[last_name]" size="20" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $SubmitForm_last_name;?>" name="SubmitForm[last_name]" /><br /><span class="error"> <?php echo $SubmitForm_last_nameError;?></span></p>
                    <p><label for="SubmitForm_job_title">Job Title</label><input type="text" id="SubmitForm[job_title]" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $SubmitForm_job_title;?>" name="SubmitForm[job_title]" /><br /><span class="error"> <?php echo $SubmitForm_job_titleError;?></span></p>
            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The third-party URL is expecting the following fields:

"SubmitForm[first_name]", "SubmitForm[last_name]" and "SubmitForm[job_title]"

Please can anybody spot why the cURL example would result in empty fields on the remote form?

Many thanks

---

### UPDATE

```
<?php
// Setup empty fields
$SubmitForm_first_name = $SubmitForm_last_name = $SubmitForm_job_title = "";
$SubmitForm_first_nameError = $SubmitForm_last_nameError = $SubmitForm_job_titleError = "";

// Validate Field Entry
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $valid = true; // Redirect if valid

    if (empty($_POST["SubmitForm_first_name"]))
    {$valid = false; $SubmitForm_first_nameError = "First name required";}
        else
        {$SubmitForm_first_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["SubmitForm_first_name"]);}

    if (empty($_POST["SubmitForm_last_name"]))
    {$valid = false; $SubmitForm_last_nameError = "Surname required";}
        else
        {$SubmitForm_last_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["SubmitForm_last_name"]);}

    if (empty($_POST["SubmitForm_job_title"]))
    {$valid = false; $SubmitForm_job_titleError = "Job title required";}
        else
        {$SubmitForm_job_title = htmlspecialchars($_POST["SubmitForm_job_title"]);}

// Start session
session_start();

// Register
session_register('SubmitForm_first_name');
session_register('SubmitForm_last_name');
session_register('SubmitForm_job_title');

// Populate
$_SESSION['SubmitForm_first_name'] = $SubmitForm_first_name;
$_SESSION['SubmitForm_last_name'] = $SubmitForm_last_name;
$_SESSION['SubmitForm_job_title'] = $SubmitForm_job_title; 

// Redirect valid form to process
if($valid)
    //set POST variables
    { $url = 'http://www.example.com/submit.php';
    $fields = array(
                        'SubmitForm[first_name]' => $SubmitForm_first_name,
                        'SubmitForm[last_name]' => $SubmitForm_last_name,
                        'SubmitForm[job_title]' => $SubmitForm_job_title
                    );

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    // redirect to thank you page
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/thanks.php');
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>

        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" name="submit_data" method="POST" id="submit_data">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Your Details</legend>
                    <p><label for="SubmitForm_first_name">First Name</label><input type="text" id="SubmitForm_first_name" size="20" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $SubmitForm_first_name;?>" name="SubmitForm_first_name" /><br /><span class="error"> <?php echo $SubmitForm_first_nameError;?></span></p>
                    <p><label for="SubmitForm_last_name">Surname</label><input type="text" id="SubmitForm_last_name" size="20" maxlength="50" value="<?php echo $SubmitForm_last_name;?>" name="SubmitForm_last_name" /><br /><span class="error"> <?php echo $SubmitForm_last_nameError;?></span></p>
                    <p><label for="SubmitForm_job_title">Job Title</label><input type="text" id="SubmitForm_job_title" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $SubmitForm_job_title;?>" name="SubmitForm_job_title" /><br /><span class="error"> <?php echo $SubmitForm_job_titleError;?></span></p>
            </fieldset>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you try to drop all the `urlencode`-ing, and just supply the _array_ with the key/value pairs to `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$array);`? Curl can convert it perfectly on its own. If you want a string for some reason (you shouldn't..), you are also better of with `$fields_string = http_build_query($your_array);`. Why is it broken now? Likely because you forgot to `urlencode` the keys themselves (`[]` => `%5B%5D`). Best way to not to forget that is to not need to remember it ;)

Comment: Thanks @Wrikken for taking the time to reply, it is much appreciated. As you may have guessed, cURL is not a method I am familiar with... I have updated my code above, to hopefully work from the array instead, but this fails to POST data too. Is "curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);" correct, since "$fields" is the array? Thank you

Comment: Well, besides setting `CURLOPT_POST` to `true` rather then counting fields (which would result in a 'truthy' value anyway), I see no reason why that shouldn't work unless the receiving party uses nonces. Are you in direct contact with them? Note that while you may be able to do a successful post to that form,  redirecting the user to that site would mean they site will still not know them, or that the post you did on their behalf relates to them in any way.

Comment: The redirect I have added at the end of the cURL section doesn't kick in at all, presumably because something is failing before it gets that far. Yet adding in the .curl_error($ch) shows no error. Or maybe I have the header Location redirect line incorrect. I think I will need to send a support message to the third-party as the script seems right. The fact it works with a direct POST though suggests it is my end though. Thanks for your help once again.

Comment: Your header line looks just fine.  Maybe try adding in an `exit;` after it to see if it redirects then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Quixrick and @Wrikken for the very helpful pointers.

It turned out that the third-party needed an addition specific "submit" field posting with the other fields. Adding that in posted data fine.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code, I got a notice `Notice: Undefined variable: fields_string`.  I doubt this has anything to do with it - the script ran just fine.

For some reason, `rtrim` does not seem to be chopping off that last `&` if I print out the string.  This also doesn't seem to make a difference for me.  Again, the script ran just fine.

```
rtrim($fields_string, '&');
print $fields_string;

// OUTPUTS:
// SubmitForm[first_name]=XXXXX&SubmitForm[last_name]=YYYYY&SubmitForm[job_title]=Rock+Star&
```

The script cURL calls just does a dump of $_POST and everything comes through just fine.

```
Array
(
    [SubmitForm] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => XXXXX
        [last_name] => YYYYY
        [job_title] => Rock Star
    )

)
```

So maybe try doing a dump of `$_POST` on your destination script and see if you get the same thing.  If not, then I suspect it's an error with cURL.  Try adding in some error checking to your cURL request.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    print 'CURL Error: '.curl_error($ch);
}
```

See if that gives you an error of some sort.  A common problem is to be connecting to an `https` URL and it can't verify the SSL certificate.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. The print $fields_string line shows the data fine in the output, so the data appears to collect fine. There must be an issue as it attempts to submit, as the script is not getting as far as the "header('Location...)" line. However, using the print error line you provided displays nothing. cURL is fine my end, so I will send a support request to the third-party. Thanks again.